# Python: list index out of range. I don't know how to fix this

Tags: python, list, range

```
def RPS():
    userRPS = input("Rock, paper, or scissors? ")
    RPSlist = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    computerRPS = RPSlist[randint(1,3)]
    print("\nI chose " + computerRPS + ", and you chose " + userRPS)
    elif userRPS == "scissors":
        if computerRPS == "rock":
            print("You lose.")
        elif computerRPS == "paper":
            print("You win.")
        elif computerRPS == "scissors":
            print("I chose scissors too. Go again.")
            RPS()
    else:
        print("?")
        RPS()
```

So if I make the else statement run, it prints list index out of range. The same happens if the user and the random generator choose the same thing. I tried to learn how to fix this, but I really don't understand any of the explanations.

Comment: Could you please add a full copy of the error message? The error message should tell yo which lines we should take a deeper look at...

Comment: also, there is a syntax error with this code ... it won't run. the first "elif" should be "if"

Comment: change `randint(1,3)` to `randint(0,2)`; reminder that lists are zero index so lists of size 3 have indices 0-2

Comment: `computerRPS = RPSlist[randint(1,3)]` should be `computerRPS = RPSlist[randint(0,2)]` no?

Comment: sorry guys. that's because I didn't want to include too much code in my message.

Comment: Consider selecting an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing randint(0, 2) because RPSList is zero indexed. That fixes the out of range error but you should also be doing "if...else" instead of "elif...else".

Comment: thanks. sorry about the syntax error. i didn't want to include unnecessary code. and that was the last of my if statements. so i forgot to delete the "el"

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do what you want would be to use `random.choice`.

e.g.

```
import random

RPSlist = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
print(random.choice(RPSlist))
```

That way you don't have to concern yourself with how long the list is.

So that line becomes

```
computerRPS = random.choice(RPSlist)
```

Also you cannot have an `elif` without a preceding `if`. So you just need to change that `elif` to `if`.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of changes:

```
elif userRPS == "scissors":
```

Should be

```
if userRPS == "scissors":
```

And

```
computerRPS = RPSlist[randint(1,3)]
```

should be

```
computerRPS = RPSlist[randint(0,2)]
```

Always remember that list indexes count from `0`, not from `1`.

Answer (score 0):

refering to your this part of your question

**I really don't understand any of the explanations.**

Before you edit you question you **had**

```
computerRPS = RPSlist[randint(0,3)]
```

now after the edit your new command was

```
computerRPS = RPSlist[randint(1,3)]
```

Both will cause a list index out of range why?

Take for example `computerRPS = RPSlist[randint(1,3)]`

This **may** generate

```
RPSlist[1]
RPSlist[2]
RPSlist[3]
```

**but your RPSlist has three elements starting from 0**

```
RPSlist = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
             ^        ^         ^
             0        1         2
```

now if `randint(1,3)` gave you a random number like **3**.your variable will be

```
RPSlist[3]
```

but you are array doesn't have any variable with index of 3.maximum indexed element is 2

**Hence you get an index out of range error**